# acf function producing slightly inaccurate result

Tags: r, time-series, regression, autocorrelation

The autocorrelation command acf is slightly off the correct value. the command i am giving is `acf(X,lag.max = 1)` and the output is 0.881 while the same autocorrelation calculation done using the command cor(X[1:41],X[2:42]) gives the value 0.9452. I searched a lot to understand if there is any syntax I am missing or if the two computations have some fundamental difference but could not find suitable resources. Please help.

Comment: Could you add tags for the programming language and for the library that `acf` comes from?

Answer (score 1):

The equation for autocorrelation used by `acf()` and in all time series textbooks is

[image]

where

[image]

See https://otexts.com/fpp2/autocorrelation.html for example.

The equation for regular correlation is slightly different:

[image]

where

[image]

The simpler formula is better because it uses all available data in the denominator.

Note also that you might expect the top formula to include the multiplier $T/(T-k)$ given the different number of terms in the summations. But this is not included to ensure that the corresponding autocorrelation matrix is nonnegative definite.

Comment: Helo Rob! thanks for the answer. I doubt there is a slight error in the code of y1 bar and y2 bar but I get your point. Can you also clarify which one to use for evaluating the unit root behaviour  of a variable in time series analysis.

Comment: I've converted the equations to images. For time series you should use the equation at the top.